# Determine whether {q∧(p→¬q)}→¬p is tautology without a truth table (using logic laws and propositional equivalence)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

how can I prove whether {q∧(p→¬q)}→¬p is tautology or not?
Stuck on the (p→¬q) part, I know that  p→q is equivalent to ¬p V q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite $p\to\neg q$ as $\neg p\lor\neg q$. Then conjunction with $q$ obtains $\neg p$, so the original truth function is indeed tautological.

Comment: Thank you so much!